# Postfix/Dovecot fails to send emails "SASL PLAIN authentication failed" - no further message

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot, sasl

I have been all around the houses trying to configure Postfix and Dovecot so I can send through my domain from Gmail, which as far as I know is simply Gmail acting as a regular SMTP client talking to my server.

I have run in many circles but got to the point where my log shows  `warning: mail-qt1-f122.google.com[200.85.160.182]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:` - there is no further explanation of what the nature of the failure was, just that message.

The output of `postconf -n` looks like this:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost, mydomain.com
myhostname = mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = mydomain.com
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_sasl_type = dovecot
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

And `doveconf -n` gives me:

```
# 2.3.4.1 (f79e8e7e4): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.4 ()
# OS: Linux 4.19.0-26-cloud-amd64 x86_64 Debian 10.13
# Hostname: vps758210
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_home = /home/vmail/%d/%n
mail_location = mbox:~/mail
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

The logs around the above message look like this:

```
Feb  1 13:29:34 vps758210 postfix/smtpd[20106]: connect from mail-qt1-f122.google.com[200.85.160.182]
Feb  1 13:29:34 vps758210 postfix/smtpd[20106]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-qt1-f122.google.com[200.85.160.182]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature ECDSA (P-256) server-digest SHA256
Feb  1 13:29:38 vps758210 postfix/smtpd[20106]: warning: mail-qt1-f122.google.com[200.85.160.182]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
Feb  1 13:29:38 vps758210 postfix/smtpd[20106]: lost connection after AUTH from mail-qt1-f122.google.com[200.85.160.182]
Feb  1 13:29:38 vps758210 postfix/smtpd[20106]: disconnect from mail-qt1-f122.google.com[200.85.160.182] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/1 commands=3/4
```

I've found a lot of questions that seem related but it's hard to search for a message *without* any further data given. What is missing from this configuration?

Comment: Could you clarify what you call "the Gmail SMTP connector"? The configs don't show anything related to Gmail. Also, show the full postfix log entry for the failing message.

Comment: I mean using GMail as an SMTP client to send emails from my domain. That is the whole postfix log entry for the failing message, there are a few surrounding lines that show GMail connecting and disconnecting but this is all the information Postfix is giving me about the problem.

Comment: The log shows that it is Gmail connecting to your server trying to deliver a message to your server. It is quite the opposite of "send emails from my domain".

Comment: What would it look like if Gmail was acting as an SMTP client connecting to my server in order to send a message? Because I think that is what is supposed to be happening...

Comment: The subject of your question says that "Postfix/Dovecot fails to send". There are no logs showing Postfix attempting to send anything. There is instead a log showing Gmail attempting to deliver to your server, which is the opposite of the initial question. You need to improve your question as you are either missing some details or making some assumptions about what is supposed to be happening.

Comment: Gmail has a "send as" feature where you get it to send from your domain by connecting to your server over SMTP. That is what I'm trying to use. The problem is that it doesn't send. The _cause_ of the problem might be somewhere else in the process, but the outcome is that it doesn't send. The question documents all the information I have about what is going on. If there is a useful way to get more debugging data I'd love to hear about it, but this is everything I know. Would you say the problem is that it's rejecting SMTP connections?

Comment: You are trying to use SMTP instead of *submission(s)* which would be more appropriate for this use case.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I do have submission enabled, what do I need to configure differently to get it working?

Comment: Use the submission port on the Gmail connector. The `postfix/smtpd` instance in the logs instead of `postfix/smtpd/smtps` or `postfix/smtpd/submission` suggests you are using SMTP port `25`.

Comment: That's weird, I am definitely telling GMail to connect to 587. I wonder why it isn't.